# How to get a requested directory and resolve it to a file

Tags: php, apache, file, .htaccess, directory

I am wondering how I can get a request directory, lets call it http://doamin.com/page/ and get it to resolve to a page like http://doamin.com/page1.php but still show in the URL as the directory.

From a bit of research I think it will be something in the .htaccess file however I am not quite sure what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place these directives in your `.htacess`, note that these rules  will redirect also /page (without trailing slash) to /page.php, if you don't want that just remove the trailing `?` in the RewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^\.]+?)/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* %1.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for responding,what you have done works, however the includes mess up, is there a way of fixing this?